# Sizing of Inverter Circuit

Tags: mosfet

I'm just embarking on a new design assignment and I was wondering - where do you guys start with sizing? What's your train of thought? So many devices, which do I start with first?

The circuit is a bootstrapped switch. I'm currently focussing on the first part, which is the clock-boosting circuit. The circuit shown below

[image]

I decided to start with the inverter at the very left. Here is my train of thought:

- Inverter consists of a PMOS and an NMOS device. The lengths are fixed due to the process (180nm). The width of the PMOS device in the inverter is usually twice as much as the NMOS due to the low mobility of holes.
- At the very initial stage where the capacitors on the left are discharged, this inverter will need to drive the gate of T2 and the parasitics on that node and also the gate of T11.

I was thinking that maybe I can use the parasitics capacitances and some parasitic resistances to get a time constant and make sure that is less than my clock period? But I don't have any parasitic resistances in my schematic?

**How do I begin to size the inverters?** I also don't have capacitor sizes either. All I know is the sampling frequency and hold capacitor size as well as supply voltage and required SNR.

Comment: Why do you start at that end? Sizing will obviously depend on how much current you have to deliver, so start at the output stage and work backwards! The clock buffering will have to drive a few gates, and the speed of switching and the capacity of these gates will define how strong these (inverting) buffers need to be - and those parameters are again defined by the output stage considerations.

Comment: School or work environment? I don't do IC design but if you are in a work environment you should be able to look at previous designs on the same process to see what sizes were used. I would start there. If you are a student then it makes sense to do everything the "correct way" so you learn how to do it from first principles. Seems like you would start at the last load and work backwards, but I am not sure.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Apologies for the delay. I see. So should I start by sizing the hold capacitor based on thermal noise requierments. Then use i=Cdv/dt to find max current that T12 needs to provide? Now if I have that max current, how do I size T12? It isn't in saturation.